# Android-Simulate mouseover/hover

Tags: java, android

How can you simulate a mouseover event in an android app?
I have to detect if the user is touching/hovering over a particular part of the screen for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: How would the user "hover"? Placing the finger on the screen for two seconds would be a long-tap.

Answer (score 0):

you cant hover without a cursor.

but for an ipad there is a simulate hover command for css. unfortently i cant find it, if anyone does find it let me know!

i used it in some code once, im scouring that code for it, im hoping i didnt imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

Case: I wanted a pointer to move a mouse around the screen of my phone via my watch. If somebody finds this in the future:

Pointer image: Tasker allows to create scenes. Create a scene with a canvas as big as you want your pointer to be, add the image you want as pointer as the scene only element, filling the scene.

Coordinates static: Create variables for "X" and "Y" (these are STILL NOT pixels). You want to play around with values on the show scene location applying your variables. 0,0 is top left, 200,200 is bottom right.

Coordinates movement: My approach was having 2 variables "now" and "final" (or other names). So you can tell tasker: Hide scene in Xnow,Ynow; Show scene in Xfinal,Yfinal; Set variables Xnow to Xfinal and Ynow to Yfinal.

With that in mind:
You may want to detect if "mouse overlay image is on top of your desired element.

Answer (score -1):

With a touch screen, users can only touch or not touch, but not hover, so that this part of the question is probably out.

The long touch behavior is implemented inside the various `onXXXLongClick()` handlers.

Answer (score -1):

[How to hover over a link?](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-2-general-discussions/110239-how-hover-over-link.html)

I hope this link helps you .

But how can a person hover in a touch device ? Well i have always placed my fingers .

Comment: Its for an eye gaze project on an emulator(so far). The gaze is being simulated by the mouse operating the emulator.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding onClick="return true" in your link a href tag

About us

the onClick="return true" should simulate a cursor hovering over then leaving the hover area. effectivly giving you a hover effect.

keep in mind, ur finger has to touch the button for the hover effect to take place, which means the user will only see the change for a second or two before the link loads a page.

Comment: -1 for mixing up very fundamental concepts.  Clicking and hovering are not even nearly the same thing.